# Automate pressing the My Location button on a MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a `MapView` within a `Fragment` and I'm already displaying the users location via `setMyLocationEnabled()`. Everything is working as expected.

For the typical use-case I want to zoom to the user's location - the exact behaviour of pressing the "My Location" button on the stock maps UI.

**I want to save the user from having to press the My Location button and automate this step**, but I cannot see from the APIs how to do this. I can get the `UiSettings` from the `GoogleMap` but this only seems to allow me to query/set the *state* of the map UI (i.e. whether the My Location is enable and therefore available to be pressed).

Or do I really have to setup a `LocationClient` and calculate and animate to a `CameraUpdate`? This seems like a lot of legwork to do something quite common/simple. The logic of implementing this properly (i.e. as the user would expect it to behave) is more involved than it seems at first sight and I'm keen to avoid duplicating code which has clearly already been implemented within Google Maps.

Comment: If you can get a reference to the actual View that the user would click on, you can call `performClick()` on it. The question is how to get the reference to that View...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To move the map camera position to user location you have to find the user location first and by using locationmangaer class object you can get that in onLocationChange method

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

//... 

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                        .getLongitude())) //
                .zoom(9).build();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) says the id of the "my location button" is `0x2`. So, with that information you can use [`SupportMapFragment.getView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29) to call [`View.findViewById`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29) and then [`View.performClick`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick%28%29).

Here's an example:

```
final SupportMapFragment smf = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
smf.getView().findViewById(0x2).performClick();
```

I ran this in the "My Location Demo" provided in the Google Play Services samples and it worked.

The demo is located in: `<android-sdk>/extras/google-play-services/samples/maps`

Comment: Thanks - is this approach generally frowned upon? For example could that id ever change and therefore break in a future update?

Comment: @AndrewEbling Frowned upon? I don't know about that, but of course Google *could* change the id.